Creating a Selection Box that selects a PropertyGroup item from a CollectionProperty
trying to follow the below link to make a selection box appear in the draw method that lets the user pick an item from a defined CollectionProperty, it works for the 'type=bpy.types.Object' but when I change it to my custom ItemPropertyGroup class "BlenderUnityCategoryItem", it doesn't work, I know that I need to somewhat reference my collection but I'm not sure how to do that
Creating drop down lists for the objects in collections
works fine for an object picker, eg: showing an armature picker

but it doesn't work when I use my PropertyGroup class, how do I reference my CollectionProperty?


my code(removed some lines none related to the topic so the code will be easy to read):
# imports
import bpy
import os
from bpy.types import Panel, Operator, Scene, UIList, PropertyGroup, PointerProperty

import mathutils
from math import radians

from bpy.props import StringProperty, BoolProperty, IntProperty, CollectionProperty, EnumProperty






class BlenderUnityCategoryItem(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    categoryName: bpy.props.StringProperty(name="Category Name", description="", default="")
    categoryFolder: bpy.props.StringProperty(name="Category Folder", description="", default="")




# Blender Unity Panel
class BlenderUnityPanel(Panel):
    bl_label = "Blender Unity"
    bl_idname = "BlenderUnity_Panel"
    bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"
    bl_region_type = "UI"
    bl_category = "Unity"
    
    
    
    txt_categoryName : StringProperty(name= "Category Name:", default = "")    
      
    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        scene = bpy.data.scenes["blenderunity_settings"]
        blenderunity_props = scene.blenderunity_props
        
       
        
        
        # unity project folder browser
        row = layout.row()
        
        

        
        # unity meshes folder
        row = layout.row()
        
        row.prop(scene, "my_pointer")
        

        #unityMeshesFolder
        #row.template_list("BlenderUnityUIList_DMats_UL_List", "BlenderUnityListbox_MarkExportDMats", scene, "markexport_detectedMats", scene, "markexport_detectedMats_index")
    


# register settings
def Settings():
        
    # create blender unity settings scene (if it doesn't exist)
    if(bpy.data.scenes.get("blenderunity_settings") is None):
        bpy.data.scenes.new(name="blenderunity_settings")
    
    # my defined collection
    bpy.types.Scene.blenderunity_categories = CollectionProperty(type=BlenderUnityCategoryItem)
    bpy.types.Scene.blenderunity_category_index = IntProperty(name = "blenderunity_category_index") 
    
    # pointers
    bpy.types.Scene.my_collection = bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=BlenderUnityCategoryItem)
    bpy.types.Scene.my_pointer = bpy.props.PointerProperty(
        type=BlenderUnityCategoryItem
        )

    
    #item = scene_settings.markexport_detectedMats.add()
    
    #item.custom_1 = 100

## ----------- register & unregister --------------------
def register():
    # class registers
    #bpy.utils.register_class(_CLASS_NAME)

    bpy.utils.register_class(BlenderUnityCategoryItem)
    #bpy.utils.register_class(__)
    
    # get scene
    scene = bpy.context.scene
    
   
    # setup settings scene
    Settings()

    
    bpy.utils.register_class(BlenderUnityPanel)
    
    
def unregister():
    #bpy.utils.unregister_class(_CLASS_NAME)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(BlenderUnityPanel)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(BlenderUnityCategoryItem)
    #bpy.utils.unregister_class(___)
    #bpy.utils.unregister_class(___)
    
    return ""
    
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # register 
    register()
    
     
##---------------------------------    

Blender version: 3.6.17

to make a selection box that selects an item PropertyGroup from a CollectionProperty use EnumProperty with items= set to a function
eg:
def selectedCategory_items(self, context):
    # get our settings scene
    scene = bpy.data.scenes["blenderunity_settings"]
    
    # a list to store items
    items = []
    
    items.append(("0", "None","No assigned category"))
    
    i = 1;
    for item in scene.blenderunity_categories:
        str_i = str(i)
        
        newItem = (str_i, item.categoryName, item.categoryName)
        items.append(newItem)
        i += 1
        
        
    return items  



# next you would define your EnumProperty like:
fbxCategory : bpy.props.EnumProperty(items = selectedCategory_items, name = "Category")

